# Force Google maps v2 api to refresh custom icon image

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am using the [Google static maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro?csw=1#CustomIcons) to create a map with a custom blue marker icon:

[image]

Unfortunately, I tested the url before the my custom image was online and Google seems to have cached that knowledge somehow:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.86654,-2.2480254&zoom=6&size=100x70&sensor=false&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stolencamerafinder.com%2Fimages%2Fpin-lost.png%7C51.86654,-2.2480254 *(if this image has a blue icon, then it the cache has been updated since I posted this question!)*

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.86654,-2.2480254&amp;zoom=6&amp;size=100x70&amp;sensor=false&amp;markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stolencamerafinder.com%2Fimages%2Fpin-lost.png%7C51.86654,-2.2480254">
```

I can trick it into fetching it by adding a nonsense parameter to my icon url (eg: "?a=a") :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.86654,-2.2480254&zoom=6&size=100x70&sensor=false&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stolencamerafinder.com%2Fimages%2Fpin-lost.png?a=a%7C51.86654,-2.2480254

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.86654,-2.2480254&amp;zoom=6&amp;size=100x70&amp;sensor=false&amp;markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stolencamerafinder.com%2Fimages%2Fpin-lost.png?a=a%7C51.86654,-2.2480254">
```

However I don't want to re-deploy my app just for this. My question is:

1. Is there some way to request that Google refresh their cache?
2. Does anyone know how long it may take to get updated (if at all)?

Comment: Seems fine to me, I assume their cache has been updated, if indeed that's what the problem was

Comment: experiencing the same. I think your trick will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492335/duncan) noticed first, the image looks ok now.

So, for anyone else that has this problem, it took less than a day for my image to get refreshed. Of course, YMMV.